# If $\int_{a}^{b}f=0$ and $f \geq 0$ then $\{x\in[a,b]:f(x)=0\}$ is dense set.

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function Riemann-integrable such that $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

If $\int_{a}^{b}f=0$ then $\{x\in[a,b]:f(x)=0\}$ is dense set.

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: A nice question.  It is easy for Lebesgue integral, but how can we do it without using any Lebesgue theory?

Comment: @GEdgar The posted answer, plus your invaluable addition to it, don't use any Lebesgue theory, right?

Comment: So far there is no posted answer, only a hint.  How can you complete it without Lebesgue theory?

Comment: @GEdgar See the amazing answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794822/is-the-riemann-integral-of-a-strictly-smaller-function-strictly-smaller?noredirect=1#comment3664287_1794822)

Comment: So this question may be considered a duplicate of 1794822...

Answer (score 4):

**Here is a hint:**  Suppose $A = \{x \in [a,b] : f(x) = 0\}$ is *not* dense.  Then there is some pocket $(c,d)$ in the interval $[a,b]$ untouched by $A$, i.e., $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in (c,d)$.  (Why?  What does density even mean?)

Then since $f(x) \geq 0$ by assumption, and thus $f(x) > 0$ on $(c,d)$ (since it's not equal to $0$ at any point in this interval), what can you say about $\int \limits_{c}^{d} f(x) \,dx$?  What does this imply about $\int \limits_{a}^{b} f(x) \,dx$?

Comment: So we need to ask: could $f$ be positive everywhere, but have infimum $0$ on every open subinterval?  That is, every lower sum is zero.  Then how about upper sums?

Comment: @GEdgar Great addition to the answer.

Comment: Note: a function can, indeed, be everywhere positive but have infimum zero on every open subinterval.  Thus every lower sum could be zero.  We need to show this is not possible for a Riemann-Integrable function.  Easy with Lebesgue theory.  To do this without Lebesgue theory, see the "amazing answer" cited by MathematicsStudent.