# Apostol Integral Comparison Theorem 1.5 (Page 67)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

Theorem 1.5 Comparison Theorem on page 67 of Apostal's Calculus 1. The theorem states $s(x) < t(x)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ then $\int_a^b s(x)dx < \int_a^b t(x)dx$. **Note**: $s$ and $t$ are **step functions** in this context.

I have trouble grasping why how this is true. This is my line of thought, what if the function $t(x) = \sqrt 2$ for $x\in[a,b]$, and $s(x)<t(x)=\sqrt2$ for $x\in[a,b]$, $t$ is a line and the area of the line is 0. $\int_a^b s(x)dx = \int_a^b t(x)dx - 0$. Which part am I misunderstanding, thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Assuming these are Riemann integrals (and that $a < b$), essentially you need to show that $t-s$ is continuous at some point in $[a,b]$. Then the result follows trivially. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357472/let-fa-b-to-mathbb-r-be-riemann-integrable-and-f0-prove-that-int-abf) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794822/is-the-riemann-integral-of-a-strictly-smaller-function-strictly-smaller) for more. But this result is highly nontrivial, especially for chapter 1 of a calculus book.

Comment: You've omitted a very important detail. I checked my copy of Apostol. The assumption here is that $s$ and $t$ are step functions, not arbitrary integrable functions. That makes the proof much easier. I'm editing to add this detail.

Answer (score 1):

Given a **fixed** $s(x),$ where $s(x) < t(x)$ 
for all $x \in [a,b],$ 
consider $s_1(x) = s(x) + \dfrac{1}{2} [t(x) - s(x)].$

Further consider $s_{n+1}(x) = s_n(x) + \dfrac{1}{2} [t(x) - s_n(x)].$

Clearly, for any $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}, s_n(x) < t(x)$ 
for all $x \in [a,b].$ 
Let $u(x)$ denote the $lim_{n->\infty}s_n(x).$

Further, *inspired by the OP's original line of thought,* 
for all $x\in[a,b], u(x) = t(x).$
Therefore, $\int_a^b u(x) dx = \int_a^b t(x)dx.$

**However,** $s(x)$ itself is a **fixed** function.
Let v(x) denote $t(x) - s(x).\;$ Then, for all $x \in [a,b], v(x) > 0.$
Therefore, $\int_a^b t(x)dx - \int_a^b s(x)dx = \int_a^b \{t(x) - s(x)\}dx = \int_a^b v(x) dx > 0.$

Answer (score 0):

The integral $\int_a^b t(x)\,dx$ is not the area of the line formed by the graph of $y(t(x)$, but the area **under** the graph and the $x$-axis (assuming $t(x)>0$.) Thus, when $t(x)=\sqrt2$, we have
$$
\int_a^b t(x)\,dx=\int_a^b \sqrt2\,dx=(b-a)\sqrt2>0.
$$

Comment: if $\int_a^b t(x)dx$ is the area under $y=\sqrt2$ on $[a,b]$ and the $x$-axis, then wouldn't $\int_a^b s(x)dx = \int_a^b t(x)dx$, which contradicts the Theorem, which says if $s(x)<t(x)$ for every $x$ in the interval then the integral of $s(x)$ over the domain $[a,b]$ is less than that of $t(x)$.

Comment: My answer does not mention $s(x)$ at all. It just shows the error in your argument.

Comment: Sorry, if I'm misunderstanding but I didn't mean that $\int_a^b t(x)dx$ to be the area of the line $y=\sqrt2$. I'm trying to say that on the interval $a<x<b$ $t(x)=\sqrt2$, so the integral is as you said $(b-a)\sqrt2$. 
My question has to do with defining $s(x)$ to be the union of $\int_a^b s_i(x)dx$ on the open interval, and for all $s_i(x)$ is a constant $ c_i < \sqrt2$ such that $c_1\leq c_2\leq \cdots \leq c_k < \sqrt2$.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by union of $\int_a^bs_i(x)\,dx$.

Comment: An example of what $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} \int_a^b s_i(x)dx$ could be $\int_a^b 1 dx \cup \int_a^b 1.4 dx \cup \int_a^b 1.41 dx \cup \cdots \cup \int_a^b 1.414213562dx \cup \cdots$
Sorry I think my notation is messed up...not sure if it means what I want to say.

Comment: I certainly do not know what $\int_a^b f\cup \int_a^bg$ means.